# Some Galois theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

I have a question on field extensions, and I can't seem to find precise
 answers when browsing through online notes etc.
  Here it is: suppose $K$ and $k$ are fields with $k \leq K$ and $[K : k] = m$
 is finite. Without adding extra assumptions on $m$, *when* can we conclude that 
 there is an element $f(x) \in k[x]$ of degree $m$ such that $k[x]/(f(x)) \cong K$ ? What if we replace "of degree $m$" by "of degree divisible by $m$" ?

Thanks !

Comment: Search for "simple extensions".

Answer (score 6):

This is the case iff $K/k$ is a [simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension) field extension. It is known that finite separable extensions are simple ([Primitive Element Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem)), but there are finite extensions which are not simple, for example $\mathbb{F}_p(x,y)$ over $\mathbb{F}_p(x^p,y^p)$.